# Issue with flutter_inappwebview + custom headers on Android in case with reCaptcha on the page

Tags: android, flutter, recaptcha, request-headers, flutter-inappwebview

I'm using flutter_inappwebview + I need custom headers with all requests.
Partly my problem is solved just by adding some headers to requests in native iOS/Android code.

`InAppWebView.swift`

```swift
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
if value != nil {
    request.addValue(value!, forHTTPHeaderField: "some_key")
}
load(request)
```

`InAppWebView.java`

```java
if (headers != null) {
    loadUrl(url, headers);
    return;
}
loadUrl(url);
```

for Android

But in case when page have Google reCaptcha - iOS works just fine.
But non of those methods (like loadUrl(url, headers)) is called on Android.

This methods are called instead (in case `if Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT`)

```
loadUrl("javascript:" + scriptToInject.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", ""));
```

and if higher

```
evaluateJavascript(scriptToInject, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                            if (resultUuid != null || resultCallback == null)
                                return;
                            resultCallback.onReceiveValue(s);
                        }
                    });
```

I try adding headers here. But with no luck)

```
loadUrl("javascript:" + scriptToInject.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", ""), headers);
```

Any suggestions how to achieve desired behavior (custom headers after reCaptcha is done)?